# Emulating PHP Include Statement Using Code From HTTP Requests

Tags: php, function, http, curl, include

I have a primary "driver" script written in PHP, and based on certain criteria, I'd like this script to pull code from one or more supporting servers via HTTP in order to load functions into memory as though I had done so using the PHP include statement.

Is it possible to use HTTP requests in PHP to pull data that is actually interpreted as PHP code when it is returned?

For example, suppose I used cURL or a web service to return the following text that was stored in a variable, say $URLResponse:

```
function userKeyGet() {
  return (isset($_SESSION['user_key']) ? $_SESSION['user_key'] : '-1');
  }
```

If I then used something such as eval($URLResponse), would that create the function for use during the current execution of the calling PHP script?  I've used cURL and Buzz to return JSON or similarly structured data that I've converted into an array, but not a function or class. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: if the file is not interpreted by server as executable or to be parsed it'll be served as is, so if you don't mind exposing you `php` code to the world, use `php`'s `file_get_contents()` and have the file your pulling as `.txt` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load remote PHP codes with [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php),[include_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php),[require()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) functions, It requires [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) enabled in php.ini.

```
require_once("http://www.yourserver.com/function.php");
```

Included file should contain codes and not interpreted by server as executable, so if you are using php supported web server maybe you can give another extension to remote file.

eval() will work too. If you use eval/include and declare same function two times it will raise fatal error since it is already declared. You can use object or [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to override the function.

```
$code="function userKeyGet() {
  return (isset(\$_SESSION['user_key']) ? \$_SESSION['user_key'] : '-1');
  }";

eval($code);
eval($code); # Second time using eval on $code with "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare"

# This will work
echo userKeyGet();

# An example for anonymous function way
$code="\$userKeyGet = function() {
       return (isset(\$_SESSION['user_key']) ? \$_SESSION['user_key'] : '-1');
       };";

eval($code); # this wont raise redeclare error 

echo $userKeyGet();
```